# Bottom portion of text & numbers are not showing my screen

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I think I inadvertly deleted something in my device that now makes it only display the top 2/3's of text and numbers on some apps,settings and spec stuff.

I used various antivirus apps that may have allowed me to delete important OS files as junk files or something similar.

Can you please help with suggestion on returning my Ellipsis 10 back to normal? It is not rooted. It runs Android Lollipop 5.1.

Comment: Welcome to Android Stack Exchange. I'm not quite sure what you mean in your question. What do you mean you deleted the top 2/3s of text and numbers? Also, what did you delete? It shouldn't be possible to delete anything too crucial to the system without root access. Hope to get your issue solved.

Comment: Hi.Thank you. I meant that the bottom third portion of script has been erased on words all over my  tablet . Like half of the word on the bottom as in "B" you would only be able to see the top portion of that only that letter. The bottom part would be missing and that would be that way all across the word.One app let me delete "junk"  67 UI system files and I think that may be what caused it.Can I re-Rom or re-Firmware or something my Android tablet???Can I reload Lolipop 5.1?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot to clarify the issue? Also, what is the name of the antivirus app that deleted the files? System files should not be able to be accessed if the device is not rooted.

Comment: This is a very strange issue. I've never heard of anything like this. If you could provide additional details as Andrew T. said, that would be great.

Comment: Yes.O.K.I think it might of been from a Battery Saver app.I

Comment: continued- I downloaded about 20 Battery Saver apps and Memory and Cache clean&boost apps to find the most suitable and effective ones and I think a Battery Saver App went into my UI system and wiped out a few essential!

Comment: Sorry I inexplicably keep hitting the post button!?!? But a few OS files or firmware or Bios or something or another got taken away by one of the fore mentioned apps and now part of my text is being omitted so its almost illegible in some places.I'll try to send a screen shot if I can.This app did a deep clean and removed some functional files for the basic normal operation of my Android Ellipsis tablet.How can I replace the removed part so that it will operate properly again so that I don't have missing parts on letters words and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this isn't really an answer (since I don't know what the problem is, screenshot would help), but anyway.

Firstly, try to turn your device off and then on again, it can be surprising how problems can be fixed with a simple reboot.

If a reboot does not solve the problem, what did you do before the problem appeared ? Did you install an app ? If so, uninstall it. Did you change a setting ? If so, change it back.

Try to go into the Settings, and if there is a "developer options" entry (at the bottom, under "System") go into it, and make sure the toggle at the top is set to "Off".

If nothing else works, you can always do a factory reset (which will wipe all your data), and that should fix it. (I'm not suggesting that a factory reset is necessary - it's very likely that your problem can be fixed in some other way.)

You say you installed *20* battery booster and cache cleaner apps ? That seems a bit excessive. Try to uninstall them, if you haven't already.

---

As a side note: these apps don't do *anything* which Android cannot do on it's own. (You should read [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Clean-Master-app-for-Android-really-useful))In fact, they will probably slow down your device and cause battery drain, esp. If you have 20 of them installed.

If your battery life is less than what  you'd expect, there is a "battery" menu in the settings, which will tell you exactly what used how much battery. In my experience, this is a lot more helpful than some automagic all in one battery saver app.

If your device is slow, you probably have too many apps installed - installing a cache cleaner app isn't going to fix that.

Comment: OK Thanks that was helpful.l was only trying out the twenty apps to find a couple of good ones and the one named Cleaner Pro by Adwave found some UI system apps it considered junk so I permitted it's removing them and I kinda suspect now they may have been important to the operation of my tablet.So I may eventually try a factory reset as you recommend to see if returns it to normal.I would send a screenshot but I don't know the procedure of sending to here.How do I share it or email it?And to where?I'm not familiar with the transmission of a screen shot process to here.Care to explain?

Comment: Oh incidently will a factory reset obliterate all my 190 apps???

Comment: @stanwo Yes, factory reset will delete everything, including your apps. That's why it's called factory reset, it returns your device to the state it was in whein it was entirely new. To post a screenshot here, first take a screenshot on your device, and the edit your question to upload and include the screenshot in your question, I believe there's a button to add a screenshot / image in the editor. Check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: A factory reset may not reinstall system apps that were uninstalled if this is the case since I believe that a factory reset only wipes /data and /cache...

Comment: @LJD200, OP says his device is not rooted, so no way system apps could have been uninstalled.

Comment: @JonasCz That's exactly what I thought but OP also said that it removed UI system apps and it's certainly a strange issue if no system apps were removed. This should not be able to happen and I'm not quite sure how it did...